# Excel macro copy values from one row to another without overwriting formulas in the target row

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to create a macro that copies data from the current month row to the bottom. The current month row has links in the cells, so when it is refreshed,the date and the data will change for a new month (sept--16), but before it is refreshed, copy the data to the matching month below. The balance column has a formula in each cell (total - amount). How do i copy down just the values, without overwriting the formula in the balance cell.

[image]

here is the code i have

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim compareValue As String
Dim comparingValue As String
Dim i As Long
compareValue = Cells(2, 2).Value

For i = 3 To Rows.Count
    comparingValue = Cells(i, 2).Value
    If compareValue = comparingValue Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:J2").Copy
        lRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Range("C" & lRow + 1, "J" & lRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a direct value transfer.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i, "C").resize(1, 8)
    worksheets("another sheet").cells(rows.count, "C").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).resize(1, 8) = .value
end with
```

Comment: i am a little confused by the code, could you please shed more light ?

Comment: OK, so you've stepped through the code with [F8] and set watches on one or more vars. You've also debugged the addresses out the source and the target. What part didn't you understand? I'm not prepared to write several paragraphs on what is essentially two lines of code.